# Downloading sources file to image directory

Tags: pharo, pharocloud

I am using PharoCloud to host a Pharo image for me.  By default it downloads a ZIP of the image only to my appliance; this ZIP doesn't include the .sources file.

I am trying to manually download the sources file with ZnClient.  The directory my image is located in is `/mnt/upload/upload.140605183221`.

This is the code I have

```
| aFileStream |
    aFileStream := '/mnt/universe/upload/upload.140605183221/PharoV30.sources' asFileName writeStream.
    aFileStream write: (ZnClient new get: 'http://files.pharo.org/sources/PharoV30.sources.zip').
    aFileStream close.
```

I'm brand new to ZnClient; I don't know how to use it.  What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
'./PharoV30.sources' asFileReference 
    writeStreamDo: [ :stream | 
        stream write: (ZnClient new get: 'http://files.pharo.org/sources/PharoV30.sources') contents ].
```

Comment: Worked perfectly after I changed `ZnConstants maximumEntititySize`.  Thanks!

Comment: Sending #contents will use a lot of memory space that is only used to write to a file. Instead, you can use `ZnClient>>downloadTo:`.

Answer (score 2):

Nearly right. You need to replace the message `#asFileName` with `#asFileReference`, since `#asFileName` will answer a string object (so you actually get a `WriteStream` on the string).

```
fileReference := '/mnt/universe/upload/upload.140605183221/PharoV30.sources' asFileReference
fileReference writeStreamDo: [ :stream |
    | url|
    url := 'http://files.pharo.org/sources/PharoV30.sources.zip'.
    stream write: (ZnClient new get: url) ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Getting some context and explanation for why my code won't work really helps and prepares me for future uses of ZnClient.